# How to replace a substring in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string, text, replace

I have a question involving the string `Replace` function in Visual Basic .NET:

I have a Visual Basic script for my project. I have a `RichTextBox` named `sample`

```
Dim string1 as string = "text to find"
Dim string2 as string = "text to replace find with"
Dim mediacurrent as string

mediacurrent = sample.text

mediacurrent.replace(string1, string2)

sample.text = mediacurrent
```

The above script returns a blank text box. Note the text box is rich and contains non-formatted but multiline text. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Strings are immutable in .NET, the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method returns the new value, it doesn't modify the original string on which it was called. You need to reassign it, like this:

```
mediacurrent = mediacurrent.Replace(string1, string2)
```